How can I show the label text over the textformfield in Flutter?
enter image description here
Currently, my label text is as shown. I want the label text right above each textformfield. What is the solution without creating a text in the column. My code snippet is as follows:

body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(39.0),
          child: Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 320,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color:
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
                    key: const ValueKey('Current Password'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      // if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                      //   return 'Please enter a valid email';
                      // }
                      // return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
                      labelText: 'Enter your current password',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color:
                              Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
                      // floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outline),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onSaved: (newValue) {},
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 320,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.newPassword],
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color:
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
                    key: const ValueKey('New password'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                        return 'Password must be atleast 7 characters';
                      }
                      storePassword = value;
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
                      labelText: 'Enter your new password',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color:
                              Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
                      // floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outline),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                      ),
                    ),
                    obscureText: true,
                    onSaved: (newValue) {
                      userPassword = newValue!;
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 320,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color:
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
                    key: const ValueKey('Confirm your new password'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value != storePassword) {
                        return 'Password must match';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
                      labelText: 'Confirm your new password',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color:
                              Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outline),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                      ),
                    ),
                    obscureText: true,
                    onSaved: (newValue) {
                      userPassword = newValue!;
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 25,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 320,
                  height: 50,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary)),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      'Submit',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 17,
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

I don't want to use text inside the column. I also have floatinglabel behavior set to auto, but that does not help. What is the solution for this?

Can you add where you want to see Label text expected ui?

On top of each boxes. I have to add some padding as well to give space for the same.

You can change the behavior of the label by setting the floatingLabelBehavior option. By default, the behavior is set to FloatingLabelBehavior.auto. From the docs:

When FloatingLabelBehavior.auto the label will float to the top only when the field is focused or has some text content, otherwise it will appear in the field in place of the content.
When FloatingLabelBehavior.always the label will always float at the top of the field above the content.

So in order to make the label always stay on the top of the field, set the behavior to FloatingLabelBehavior.always.
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
    // ...
  ),
  // ...
)

Please note that the label won't actually appear on the top (outside) the field, but rather it appears along with the outline. This is due to Flutter only adapts the basic floating label style from the Material 3 guidelines on outlined text field.
If you need an adjacent label instead, you need to make a custom widget with Column and Text, as you already figured it out.
